# Design relation in RDBMS

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I wanted to create a separate table for boolean/junction table with bool valus, YES/NO but not sure how to leverage on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Exercises` and `Muscle_Groups`.  The relation between them is:

One `Exercise` works one to many `Muscle_Groups`

One `Muscle_Group` used by zero-to-many `Exercises`

Therefore there is a logical association (many to many) between them which we would implement as a junction table:

```
CREATE TABLE Exercise
(
  ExerciseName  VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Exercise PRIMARY KEY (ExerciseName)
)
;
CREATE TABLE MuscleGroup
(
  MuscleGroupName  VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_MuscleGroup PRIMARY KEY (MuscleGroupName)
)
;
CREATE TABLE ExerciseMuscleGroup
(
  ExerciseName     VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
 ,MuscleGroupName  VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ExerciseMuscleGroup_Is_MuscleGroup FOREIGN KEY (MuscleGroupName) REFERENCES MuscleGroup (MuscleGroupName)
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ExerciseMuscleGroup_Worked_By_Exercise FOREIGN KEY (ExerciseName) REFERENCES Exercise (ExerciseName)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ExerciseMuscleGroup PRIMARY KEY (ExerciseName, MuscleGroupName)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_ExerciseMuscleGroup UNIQUE (MuscleGroupName, ExerciseName) /* To facilitate lookups only) */
)
;
```

Now to handle the other case which is each `Exercise` has a level associated with `MuscleGroup`.  Let's call this `ExerciseLevel` and add it to the `ExerciseMuscleGroup` table:

```
CREATE TABLE ExerciseLevel
(
  ExerciseLevelCd  CHAR(1)  NOT NULL  /* Yes here would be redundant - think low L/medium M/high H if possible */
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ExerciseLevel PRIMARY KEY (ExerciseLevelCd)
)
;

CREATE TABLE ExerciseMuscleGroup
(
  ExerciseName     VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
 ,MuscleGroupName  VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
 ,ExerciseLevelCd  CHAR(1)      NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ExerciseMuscleGroup_Is_MuscleGroup FOREIGN KEY (MuscleGroupName) REFERENCES MuscleGroup (MuscleGroupName)
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ExerciseMuscleGroup_Worked_By_Exercise FOREIGN KEY (ExerciseName) REFERENCES Exercise (ExerciseName)
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ExerciseMuscleGroup_Worked_At_ExerciseLevel FOREIGN KEY (ExerciseLevelCd) REFERENCES ExerciseLevel (ExerciseLevelCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ExerciseMuscleGroup PRIMARY KEY (ExerciseName, MuscleGroupName)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_ExerciseMuscleGroup UNIQUE (MuscleGroupName, ExerciseName)
)
;
```

Now displaying the results is a relatively easy pivot, and it's very easy to search for `Exercises` for `MuscleGroups` or the other way around.

### Inserting the Data

Since you're receiving a flat file, you'll have to unpivot the data to fit the normalized structure.  SQL Server has UNPIVOT (which is relatively easy to figure out) but recent versions of MySQL and Postgres you'll have to use a `LATERAL` join like so (credit to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64404865/13942986)

```
SELECT
  s.Exercise
 ,unp.MuscleGroup
 ,unp.ExerciseLevel
FROM
  source s
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT 'Calves',Calves
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Quad-riceps',Quadriceps
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ham-strings',Hamstrings
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Gluteus',Gluteus
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Hipsother',Hipsother
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Lowerback',Lowerback
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Lats',Lats
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Trapezius',Trapezius
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Abdominals',Abdominals
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pectorals',Pectorals
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Deltoids',Deltoids
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Triceps',Triceps
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Biceps',Biceps
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Forearms',Forearms
  ) AS unp(MuscleGroup,ExerciseLevel)
WHERE
  COALESCE(unp.ExerciseLevel,'') <> ''
```

See Fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=71623b8adce32dab6cd2d02bf8e76aa8

### Closing Note

I don't think there are enough exercises or muscle groups to warrant any usage of a code or `id`.  If it was determined that the keys were too wide (they really aren't), one could demote the existing primary key to an alternate key and replace the primary key with the code or `id`.  I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Why are we adding it ```ExerciseLevelCd``` to ```ExerciseMuscleGroup```. And can this all be added in one go i.e

```

Comment: Hi @bbaird, Don't really get what goes in each table. I have 4 tables namely ```Exercise, MuscleGroup, ExerciseLevel and ExerciseMuscleGroup```

The only table/csv I have is in the form of the first table as shown above.

Comment: @QuickSilver That data is pivoted, to "unpivot" you have a few options but you certainly do **not** want to store the data natively that way.  Is the question how to design the database or how to insert the data?

Comment: yes exactly. Since I have just one csv, I am not sure how to partition them and feed into db. Any thoughts.
I have something like below table in csv

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu8pe.png

Comment: @QuickSilver See updated answer for how to unpivot the data from a flat format.